# how to stop repeat-able javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

the case is when i clicked the "PAID" select option->the "SORTby" filter is popped out(well that's what i wanted)

but the problem is ,when i change "PAID" to "NOT PAID" and then i choose "PAID" again, the "SORTby" filter is popped out again and again .. please anyone help me how to fix it..

kindly check the code:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
var field   = $("#sortBy");
if ($('#paid_at').val() != '') {
    var url_string = window.location.href; // www.test.com?filename=test
    var url = new URL(url_string);
    var paramValue = url.searchParams.get("sort");

    if (paramValue == 'created_at_desc') {
        var html =`<select class="form-control" id="sort_by" name="sort">     
        <option value="created_at_asc">Created At (ASC)</option>
        <option value="created_at_desc" selected >Created At (DESC)</option>
        </select>`
        
    } else {
        var html =`<select class="form-control" id="sort_by" name="sort">     
        <option value="created_at_asc" selected>Created At (ASC)</option>
        <option value="created_at_desc">Created At (DESC)</option>
        </select>`
    } 
    $(html).insertAfter(field).stop();
}

$('#paid_at').on("change", function (e) {
    console.log('test');
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = $("#paid_at option:selected").val();
    if(x == 'paid'){
        var html =`<select class="form-control" id="sort_by" name="sort">     
        <option value="created_at_asc" >Created At (ASC)</option>
        <option value="created_at_desc">Created At (DESC)</option>
        </select>`
    }
    $(html).insertAfter(field).stop(); 
});
```

});

Comment: please share the more detailed code is hard to understand

Comment: The issue is that you're always adding with `.insertAfter` but never removing it.   It looks like you should add the `<select><option..` directly to the HTML then `.show()` / `.hide()` it as required as well as changing the `.val("created_at_asc")` / `_desc` as required.